# Can't connect to my NodeJS site when run as service. There are no error messages that I can find

Tags: node.js, linux, centos, centos7, systemd

I have built a basic NodeJS blog application and I am hosting it on a Centos7 Minimal VPS (OpenVZ i believe).

I have installed the appropriate Node version, MongoDB, and the npm dependencies with "npm install" after cloning from my git repository.

I can build and launch the site manually from the command line without any errors, and reach the site through a web browser to verify that everything is working.

However, when I try to start the site with 'sudo systemctl blog start', nothing appears to happen. 'stytemctl blog status' shows green "active (running)" text, but I can not connect through a browser.

```
[bbauer@blog Blog-Project]$ sudo systemctl status blog
● blog.service - blog nodejs server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/blog.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-07-20 15:56:31 EST; 2min 52s ago
 Main PID: 12451 (server.js)
   CGroup: /system.slice/blog.service
           └─12451 /usr/bin/env /var/www/Blog-Project/server.js
```

Here is my .service file from /etc/systemd/system/blog.service

```
[Unit]
Description=blog nodejs server
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/Blog-Project/server.js
Restart=always
User=root
Group=nobody
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/Blog-Project

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have made the server.js executable with this command:

```
chmod +x server.js
```

Can anyone think of something I might have missed?

contents of server.js as requested:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
// Require packages
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');


var app = express();


// Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
...... etc., etc...
```

Comment: what's in your server.js?  is your system associating .js files with node.js or do you need to specify node path in your service file?

Comment: I added the server.js file and I am noticing that I left the 'node' off at the end of the first line. I'll test now.

Comment: That was definitely the solution. Can I give you the answer somehow? I'm still new to SO.

Comment: I will add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify in server.js that it should run under node.js, like this:

```
#!/bin/env node
```

or execute it like a node script using the script name as a parameter to node on the command line.